# Qt Installer Framework : Create shortcut with argument

Tags: qt, installation

Does anyone know how to add an argument to a shortcut created by QT IFW? 
I need the exe it launches to be passed an argument.

Here's what works (with no argument):

```
component.addOperation( "CreateShortcut",
    "@TargetDir@/MyApp.exe",
    "@StartMenuDir@/@ProductName@.lnk",
    "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@",
    "iconPath=@TargetDir@/MyApp.exe",
    "iconId=0");
```

I want the exe to get something like `-c` passed to it. I've tried a few approaches, but am not having any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt Installer framework documentation is very poor, but you can read in [operations](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/operations.html) the following:
`"CreateShortcut" filename linkname [arguments]`

> Creates a shortcut from the file specified by filename to linkname. On Windows, this creates a .lnk file which can have arguments. On Unix, this creates a symbolic link.

So do it in that way:

```
component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/Appname.exe", "@DesktopDir@/Appname.lnk", "-param");
```

Result in lnk target element:
`C:\YourAppDirectory\Appname.exe -param`

EDIT:
Your case works as well for me:

```
component.addOperation( "CreateShortcut","@TargetDir@/Appname.exe","@StartMenuDir@/@‌​ProductName@.lnk", "-param", "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@",  "iconPath=@TargetDir@/Appnam‌​e.exe","iconId=0");
```

with `-param` as the last argument too.

Comment: If possible, please test this.  It's not working for me.  It returns "Unexpected token" when I do that.  Note that I do pass more parameters currently, but they are all "named" and have a specific purpose.

Comment: @BuvinJ Works well for me: `component.addOperation( "CreateShortcut","@TargetDir@/Appname.exe","@StartMenuDir@/@ProductName@.lnk", "-param", "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@", "iconPath=@TargetDir@/Appname.exe","iconId=0");` Where exactly you getting the error?

Comment: hmm... hold up.  Maybe I have a typo elsewhere.

Comment: That was it!  Awesome.  Thanks.  I was about to add some real nasty patchwork to get around what seemed like bug.